# Count nested wildcard array mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data of users and model cars:

```json
[
   {
      "user_id":"ebebc012-082c-4e7f-889c-755d2679bdab",
      "car_1a58db0b-5449-4d2b-a773-ee055a1ab24d":1,
      "car_37c04124-cb12-436c-902b-6120f4c51782":0,
      "car_b78ddcd0-1136-4f45-8599-3ce8d937911f":1
   },
   {
      "user_id":"f3eb2a61-5416-46ba-bab4-459fbdcc7e29",
      "car_1a58db0b-5449-4d2b-a773-ee055a1ab24d":1,
      "car_0d15eae9-9585-4f49-a416-46ff56cd3685":1
   }
]
```

I want to see how many users have a car_ with the value 1 using mongodb, something like:

```json
{"car_1a58db0b-5449-4d2b-a773-ee055a1ab24d": 2}
```

For this example.

The issue is that I will never know how are the fields **car_** are going to be, they will have a random structure (wildcard).

Notes:

- car_id and user_id are at the same level.
- The car_id is not given, I simply want to know for the entire database which are the most commmon cars_ with value 1.

Comment: So, is the `car_id` given and you want to operate over there? Or the `car_id` is unknown and you want to look for into entire collection?

Comment: @J.F I want to sample how many cars_id:1 are there in my entire database,

Comment: You meant  to say how to do a MongoDB query ? Or a simple Javascript (nodejs) code ?

Comment: @BinaryMan Mongodb code would do, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `_id` and convert root object to array using `$objectToArray`,
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$match` filter `root.v` is 1
- `$group` by `root.k` and get total count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      root: { $first: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $match: { "root.v": 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$root.k",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F6doy2cbx9U)